# How to send a mail directly using Mutt?

Tags: shell, command-line, mutt

Currently I am sending my mail with the following command:

```
mutt  -s "Subject of Mail" test@example.com -a  file -i bodyTextFile
```

I have my `.muttrc` file on the home directory.

It works great.

That said I would send the file directly without having to confirm on the interface the element like the recipient and all. 
Just do it all with shells' instructions.

thanks

Answer (score 9):

Feed the body on stdin instead of with `-i`. `mutt` foregoes the interactive mode when its standard input is not a terminal device and takes the body of the email from there instead like the standard `mailx` command does.

```
mutt -s 'Subject of Mail' -a "$file1" -a "$file2" -- test@example.com < bodyTextFile
```

Or:

```
mutt -s 'Subject of Mail' -a"$file1" -a"$file2" -- test@example.com < bodyTextFile
```

Note that the `--` to mark the end of options is necessary as long as you use `-a`, even if you write it `mutt -afile -s subject -- address` where without it, it would still want to add `address` as a second attachment.

You could also do:

```
mutt -s 'Subject of Mail' -a "$file1" "$file2" -- test@example.com < bodyTextFile
```

As shown in the help message:

```
$ mutt -h
  -a <file> [...] --    attach file(s) to the message
                the list of files must be terminated with the "--" sequence
```

But that wouldn't work properly if `$file2` started with `-`, so it is better avoided.

If you have a `$list` array with the list of attachments, you'd use `-a$list` in `rc`¹/`es`/`fish` or `zsh -o rcexpandparam` or `-a$^list` in `zsh` or `"${list[@]/#/-a}"` in `bash`/`zsh` or `"${list[@]/*/-a\0}"` in `ksh93`.

---

<sup>¹ not when `$list` may be empty in `rc`</sup>

Comment: thanks it works great :), so feeding with stdin avoid to trigger the interface, do you know the reason behind that? Because after all the interface was also about the confirmation of the mail and all. Also when I use the following syntax `mutt -a file -s "Subject of Mail" horizoncoding.services@gmail.com < hello
` it returns me _Can't stat test@example.com: No such file or directory
test@example.com: unable to attach file._ despite the fact I have change the name with the real name file on my hard drive. When I deplace -a file at the end of the command it works.

Comment: @Webwoman, you're right, mutt's -a allows a list of files that end in --, instead of requiring one -a per file to attached.

Comment: @Webwoman, still, using several `-a`s is preferable here. See how I improved your edit.

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be simplified.

If you do need **attachment**, use:

```
$ mutt -a LICENSE -s "README on body, attached LICENSE" -- john@doe.cc < README
```

If no **attachs** are needed, just:

```
$ mutt -s "Tatoo" -- john@doe.cc < README
```